# Issues in setting cookies for store form input values in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I took below code from online,

```
    var myValues = [];
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    validateEmail(inputs[i]);
    myValues.push(inputs[i].value);
}

// Save them fot later use
localStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);

// After clicking the button you can retrieve them back
var oldValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.myValues);
```

I created simple asp page,

Now, If i click the next after after enter some input value, it will go to next page, and again i click back, it doesn't show entered input values.

I need to show that values, may i know, how can i achieve this one thanks in advance.

Here is the worked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/9/)

I need to add with my existing javascript code for achieving my need.

But i just confused, how to add code?

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page load, you must add the following code:

```
var $inputs = $(".input");
var myValues = localStorage.getItem("myValues") ? JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("myValues") ) : [];
for(var i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
     $inputs[i].value = myValues[i];   
}
```

This will make sure that on page load, if any data is present in the localStorage it will be populated in the respective input fields.

Now when you click on `next` button:

```
    $("#nextbutton").click(function () {
        var myValues = [],
            $inputs = $('.input');
        for (i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++) validateEmail($inputs[i]);
        if ($('.invalid').length !== 0) return false;
        for (i = 0; i < $inputs.length; i++) {
            myValues.push($inputs[i].value)
        }
        localStorage.myValues = JSON.stringify(myValues);
    });
```

This is used to store the data into the localStorage after validation.

Comment: may i now, where i can add your code from my existing code? thanks

Comment: The first snippet you must add inside your window.onload while the second snippet you need to replace the event handler which you have

Comment: can you please update my jsfiddle link.?. i just confused, thanks

Comment: Now only i check with your answer, now it didn't show even my four textboxes.. thanks.. i mean it didn't work..

Comment: now page looks like this http://s21.postimg.org/nvrt4cgdz/Untitled_1_copy.png . . the input values are fixed in textboxes, when i click next button, its nothing change.. what i need is , when i click next button, it will got next link(that time, the entered input values are cleared), again i will click back button means, it should the entered input values in text boxes.. thanks

Comment: Put the first piece of snippet inside the back button event handler. It will populate the text boxes again. Else setup a fiddle with full functionality i'll edit it there

Comment: Am not a asp.net guy. Sorry, I couldn't help you further. But the code I've provided works in jsfiddle. As mentioned you need to place it in proper location in your existing code and it will work

Comment: If i show my full code, surely you will say, where i can add.. thats why i am asking you? thanks.

Comment: @saina I would suggest you to raise another question with necessary ASP.net code and JS code in SO.

Comment: Yes, i raised.. but i can't get a solution, but i think, your answer will be work, thanks..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75165/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-saina).